# Android Seekbar - put all seekbar at 0 when you increase a seekbar

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have created an application with 3 search bars in an activity page. I want to set all search bars to 0 when I move a search bar, as shown in the image.
[screenshot apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZAkh.png)

I tried to do it as a group of togglebutton but it doesn't work.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options_page)

    image_lightr.setOnClickListener {
        finish()
    }
    val groupSeekBar = arrayOf(seekBar_global, seekBar_left, seekBar_right)
    val groupToggleButton = arrayOf(heart_toggle, dimming_toggle, chenillard_toggle)
    for (toggle in groupToggleButton){
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener { v, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked)
                groupToggleButton.forEach { if (it !=toggle) it.isChecked = false }
        }
    }

    for (seekbar in groupSeekBar){
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener{v, isChanged ->
            if(isChanged){
                groupSeekBar.forEach { if (it != seekbar) it.progress = false}
            }

        }
    }
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    actionBar?.hide()
    supportActionBar?.hide()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
        seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object: SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
        override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {
            seekBar2.progress = 0
            seekBar3.progress = 0
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
            // Do nothing
        }

    })

    seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object: SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
        override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {
            seekBar1.progress = 0
            seekBar3.progress = 0
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
            // Do nothing
        }

    })

    seekBar3.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object: SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
        override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {
            seekBar1.progress = 0
            seekBar2.progress = 0
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
            // Do nothing
        }

    })
```

This will be the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks Yousuf, I adapted it to my use case and it works perfectly.

Comment: No problem P.Congré